# An existing mdadm RAID5 is not mounting, Either a problem drive or Superblock

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5, superblock

I have 4 x 3TB NAS setup as RAID5 which has been working great for almost a year.

After a recent abrupt shutdown (had to hit the power button) the RAID will no longer mount on boot up.

I've run:

`mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bcdefghijklmn]1 >> raid.status`

The output is below:

> /dev/sda:
>   Magic : a92b4efc
>   Version : 1.2
>   Feature Map : 0x0
>   Array UUID : 7d2a94ca:d9a42ca9:a4e6f976:8b5ca26b
>   Name : BruceLee:0  (local to host BruceLee)
>   Creation Time : Mon Feb  4 23:07:01 2013
>   Raid Level : raid5
>   Raid Devices : 4
>
> Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Array Size : 8790405888 (8383.18 GiB 9001.38 GB)
>   Used Dev Size : 5860270592 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Data Offset : 262144 sectors
>   Super Offset : 8 sectors
>   State : active
>   Device UUID : 2c1e0041:21d926d6:1c69aa87:f1340a12
>
> Update Time : Sat Dec 27 20:54:55 2014
>   Checksum : d94ccaf5 - correct
>   Events : 17012
>
> Layout : left-symmetric
>   Chunk Size : 128K
>
> Device Role : Active device 0
>   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
>   /dev/sdb:
>   Magic : a92b4efc
>   Version : 1.2
>   Feature Map : 0x0
>   Array UUID : 7d2a94ca:d9a42ca9:a4e6f976:8b5ca26b
>   Name : BruceLee:0  (local to host BruceLee)
>   Creation Time : Mon Feb  4 23:07:01 2013
>   Raid Level : raid5
>   Raid Devices : 4
>
> Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Array Size : 8790405888 (8383.18 GiB 9001.38 GB)
>   Used Dev Size : 5860270592 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Data Offset : 262144 sectors
>   Super Offset : 8 sectors
>   State : active
>   Device UUID : a0261c8f:8a2fbb93:4093753a:74e7c5f5
>
> Update Time : Sat Dec 27 20:54:55 2014
>   Checksum : 7b84067b - correct
>   Events : 17012
>
> Layout : left-symmetric
>   Chunk Size : 128K
>
> Device Role : Active device 1
>   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
>   /dev/sdc:
>   Magic : a92b4efc
>   Version : 1.2
>   Feature Map : 0x0
>   Array UUID : 7d2a94ca:d9a42ca9:a4e6f976:8b5ca26b
>   Name : BruceLee:0  (local to host BruceLee)
>   Creation Time : Mon Feb  4 23:07:01 2013
>   Raid Level : raid5
>   Raid Devices : 4
>
> Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Array Size : 8790405888 (8383.18 GiB 9001.38 GB)
>   Used Dev Size : 5860270592 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Data Offset : 262144 sectors
>   Super Offset : 8 sectors
>   State : active
>   Device UUID : 9dc56e9e:d6b00f7a:71da67c7:38b7436c
>
> Update Time : Sat Dec 27 20:54:55 2014
>   Checksum : 749b3dba - correct
>   Events : 17012
>
> Layout : left-symmetric
>   Chunk Size : 128K
>
> Device Role : Active device 2
>   Array State : AAA. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
>   /dev/sdd:
>   Magic : a92b4efc
>   Version : 1.2
>   Feature Map : 0x0
>   Array UUID : 7d2a94ca:d9a42ca9:a4e6f976:8b5ca26b
>   Name : BruceLee:0  (local to host BruceLee)
>   Creation Time : Mon Feb  4 23:07:01 2013
>   Raid Level : raid5
>   Raid Devices : 4
>
> Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Array Size : 8790405888 (8383.18 GiB 9001.38 GB)
>   Used Dev Size : 5860270592 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
>   Data Offset : 262144 sectors
>   Super Offset : 8 sectors
>   State : clean
>   Device UUID : 81e5776f:2a466bee:399251a0:ab60e9a4
>
> Update Time : Sun Nov  2 09:07:02 2014
>   Checksum : cb4aebaf - correct
>   Events : 159
>
> Layout : left-symmetric
>   Chunk Size : 128K
>
> Device Role : Active device 3
>   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)

When checking the Disks in Ubuntu Disk Manager
sda/b/c are are showing as OK
and sdd is showing as OK with 64 bad sectors

If I run `fsck /dev/md0`

It reads:

> fsck.ext2: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/md0
>
> The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
>   filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
>   filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
>   is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
>   e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
>   or
>   e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Lastly if I run

`mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-d] | egrep 'Event|/dev/sd'`

I get:

> /dev/sda:
> Events : 17012
> /dev/sdb:
> Events : 17012
> /dev/sdc:
> Events : 17012
> /dev/sdd:
> Events : 159

If I run `cat /proc/mdstat` I get:

> Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
>   md0 : inactive sdb[1](S) sdc[2](S) sdd[3](S) sda[0](S)
>   1172054204Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
>   md0 : inactive sdb[1](S) sdc[2](S) sdd[3](S) sda[0](S)
> 11720542048 blocks super 1.2
>
> unused devices: <none>
>
> 8 blocks super 1.2
>
> unused devices: <none>

Lastly running `file -s /dev/md0`

I get:

> /dev/md0: empty

Basically I think I need to run --assemble on the RAID but I'm afraid of losing my data but also that 4th drive concerns me a little.

Could someone advise of the best next logical steps to get this up and running again?

Comment: the output is badly formatted (missing newlines), can you edit it? Also include `/proc/mdstat` and `file -s /dev/md0`...

Comment: Hi frostschutz, thanks for helping out.

I now know StackExchange allows basic HTML which is better for me.

I'm itching to run --assemble, but just trying to bide my time to ensure anything I attempt isnt going to cost me my data.

Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 2):

I have had the most success by executing the following strategy:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 --chunk=128 --layout=left-symmetric /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 missing
```

That creates the device with the same parameters as originally used. The `missing` causes the device to be created in degraded mode, hence no resyncing of the disks will occur. You can then check that the filesystem is intact (modulo the unclean shutdown); if so, you can proceed by adding `/dev/sdd1` to the array:

```
# mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1
```

`mdadm` will now rebuild `/dev/sdd1` from the existing raid array.

Of course you may prefer doing a `--stop` followed by a `--assemble`, but the above has worked for me in the past after a wrong disk was hot-swapped after another disk had failed.

Note that you /dev/sdd1 was apparently already offline for 4 weeks. I recommend using some monitoring script that notifies you about md failures; in Debian that's provided automatically by the `/etc/cron.daily/mdadm` script, which basically does:

```
mdadm --monitor --scan --oneshot
```

It can also be done by `mdadm` running as a daemon:

```
mdadm --monitor --pid-file /run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
```

You can provide an email address to receive alerts with `--mail mail@example.com`; of course your system needs to be able to send emails in that case...